# openui5 grid layout formatting

Tags: grid-layout, sapui5

I have a openui5 dialog with a grid layout in it. dialog is constructed with an xml view, a couple of buttons and the call

```
    //
    // Create view
    //
    var view = sap.ui.view({
        type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.XML, 
        viewName:"some.viewname"
    });

    blahDialog = new sap.ui.commons.Dialog({
        modal : true,
        title: "Create New Blah",
        buttons : [ btnSave, btnCancel ],
        content : [ view ]
    });
```

in the xml view I have a grid. One column for the label, one column for the UI element the user enters her data. This element can be a textfield, datepicker, dropdown, whatever. I have planned 2 columns for the label, 6 for the UI elements. Works fine so far.
But now I have a new requirement. In the first row, I want 2 small buttons right to the text field. So I gave the text field only 4 cols and the remaining 2 for the new buttons, 1 for each. The buttons only contain an icon so they are not very large.
This is how the dialog looks like:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25030606/pic.png

Here is the XML:

```
<mvc:View xmlns:c="sap.ui.core" 
       xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
       xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout"
       xmlns="sap.ui.commons"
       controllerName="exporgui5.expensedialog"
       xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
       width="360px">
<l:Grid>
<l:content>
  <Label text="Trip">
    <layoutData>
      <l:GridData span="L2" />
    </layoutData>
  </Label>
  <TextField width="100%" value="Some value" editable="false">
    <layoutData>
      <l:GridData span="L4"/>
    </layoutData>
  </TextField>
  <Button icon="icons/luggage--plus.png"><layoutData>
      <l:GridData span="L1"/>
    </layoutData>
  </Button>
  <Button icon="icons/bin-metal-full.png"><layoutData>
      <l:GridData span="L1"/>
    </layoutData>
  </Button>
  <Label text="Expense Type">
    <layoutData>
      <l:GridData span="L2" />
    </layoutData>
  </Label>
  <DropdownBox id="drpExpenseType"
               items="{expTypes>/k}" 
               displaySecondaryValues="true" 
               change="onExpTypeChange"  width="100%">
    <layoutData>
      <l:GridData span="L6"/>
    </layoutData>
    <c:ListItem text="{expTypes>shortName}" additionalText="{expTypes>description}" key="{expTypes>id}"/>
  </DropdownBox>
  <Label text="Date">
    <layoutData>
      <l:GridData span="L2" />
    </layoutData>
  </Label>
  <DatePicker locale="DE" id="date" yyyymmdd="{svModel>/dateValue}" change="onDateChange"  width="100%">
    <layoutData>
      <l:GridData span="L6" />
    </layoutData>
  </DatePicker>
</l:content>
</l:Grid>
</mvc:View>
```

I thought in one row I can put elements whose width sums up to some total number of columns, in my case this is 8. And as long as I don't do this button thingy it works that way. Why does the "Expense Type" label show up in the first row? What do I have to do so that the text field for trip spans over 4 columns and the 2 button come right next to it?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Kai

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation of the Grid, the sum per row is 12. If you want to have the text field and the two buttons in one row you can assign the following spans:

```
TextField: 8
Button 1:  2
Button 2:  2
     SUM: 12
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the grid layout but I'd try using a matrix layout. You'll have more control over your rows and still have a grid like layout. 
As I'm not experienced in XML views I unfortunately can't help you with the code but here's the associated documentation: https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/test-resources/sap/ui/commons/demokit/MatrixLayout.html

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `defaultSpan` attribute to your View:

```
<l:Grid
    ...
    defaultSpan="L3 M5 S12"
>
```

According to [API-doc](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.layout.Grid.html#getDefaultSpan) this specifies the number of "cols" an element in the grid can use. L, M and S are the screen-resolutions. Max number of cols are 12 in Grid-Layout.